# to-be-continous Mkdocs gitlab-ci template, why variant usage?

Tags: gitlab-ci, mkdocs, to-be-continuous

To deploy pages on gitlab, we needs to add a "variant" include.

Why it's an external yaml file and don't use the same template file with an option to (de)activate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another very pragmatic reason is that the job to deploy [GitLab pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_from_scratch.html) is mandatorily named `pages`.

If *to be continuous* has several templates that support GitLab pages deployment, they can't all declare a `pages` job or you'll have name collision troubles when including them all.

That's why GitLab pages jobs have necessarily to be in an optional additional template: that's what we call [variants](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/self-managed/advanced/#template-variants).

Answer (score 1):

The mkdocs template is a `build` type template and it should not impose the deployment method.
What if I want to deploy my documentation on a S3 bucket ? on CloudFoundry ?

Deploying on GitLab pages is a very simple use case (no envs support) so a simple solution is provided as a variant :).